# Copy tables in informix

Tags: sql, informix

How can I efficiently copy a table within an informix database? I would like to do something like

```
create table new_table as (select * from old_table)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

If you only need a temporary table, then:

```
SELECT * FROM old_table INTO TEMP new_table;
```

If you need a permanent table, then there isn't (yet) a simple way to do it.  You have to determine the schema of the old table, use it to create the new table, then use:

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

The fiddly bit is determining the schema of the old table.  `dbschema -d database -t old_table` more or less provides the information you need.

Answer (score 5):

in informix 12.10 you can now

```
create table newtable as select * from oldtable;
```